# How can i set the result of a method in a toString

Tags: java, oop, methods, tostring

I want to display the result of a method in my ToString, how can I do that? 
here is my code so far: 
you can see at the bottom line that I don't know what to write for getting the result of the "updatedPrice", can u help?

```
        public double updatedPrice(double price){
        this.price=price;

        double ChangePriceRate, ChangePriceAmount, finalPrice;

        if(name=="Bamba"){
            ChangePriceRate = 0.15;
        }else{
            ChangePriceRate = 0.05;
        }

        ChangePriceAmount = price * ChangePriceRate;

        if(name=="Bamba"){
            finalPrice = price + ChangePriceAmount;
        }else{

            finalPrice = price - ChangePriceAmount;
    }




    }

    public String toString (){

        return  "Name of the Snack: "+name+ "\n"+
                "Name of the Company: "+comp+ "\n"+
                "Price before discount: "+this.price+ "\n"+
                "Price after discount: "+        **finalPrice?**      + "\n";
    }
```

**b.t.w** - I'm really new to this, a total begginer.**
thank you.

Comment: Your code will not compile. There is no return statement in the method `updatedPrice(double price)`

Comment: 1)use "return finalPrice;" in your updatePrice method. In the toString() call the updatePrice method
2) change updatePrice to void and make finalPrice an instance variable rather than method local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call your method there:

```
public String toString (){
    return  "Name of the Snack: " + name + "\n" +
            "Name of the Company: " + comp + "\n" +
            "Price before discount: " + this.price+ "\n" +
            "Price after discount: " + updatedPrice(this.price) + "\n";
}
```

---

**Attention:**
Generally I would advise AGAINST calling methods in the `toString()` method.
It would be better if you only show the state of the class inside `toString()` and therefore only show the values of existing fields.

---

This means in consequence that you should introduce a field called `finalPrice` and store your value there.
After that you can show this value using the `toString()` method:

```
public static class MyClass {

    private String name;
    private String comp;
    private double price;
    private double finalPrice; // <-- Field for final price

    [...]    

    public void updatePrice(double price) {
      this.price = price;

      double changePriceRate;
      double changePriceAmount;

      if ("Bamba".equals(this.name)) { // <-- Use equals()!
        changePriceRate = 0.15;
      } else {
        changePriceRate = 0.05;
      }

      changePriceAmount = price * changePriceRate;

      if ("Bamba".equals(this.name)) { // <-- Use equals()!
        finalPrice = price + changePriceAmount;
      } else {
        finalPrice = price - changePriceAmount;
      }
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "Name of the Snack: " + name + "\n" +
             "Name of the Company: " + comp + "\n" +
             "Price before discount: " + price + "\n" +
             "Price after discount: " + finalPrice + "\n";
    }
  }
```

---

**Bonus point:**
Do not use `==` for comparing strings, use `equals()` instead if you want to compare the contents of strings!

Comment: +1 for recommending not to call the method in `toString()` and referring to the state of the object - exactly what I was just about to answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

create a property finalPrice and assign the value to

```
this.finalPrice = /*the price*/
```

and your code will work

Answer (score 0):

store the finalPrice variable as an instance variable:

```
double finalPrice;

    public double updatedPrice(double price){
        this.price=price;

        double ChangePriceRate, ChangePriceAmount;

        if(name=="Bamba"){
            ChangePriceRate = 0.15;
        }else{
            ChangePriceRate = 0.05;
        }

        ChangePriceAmount = price * ChangePriceRate;

        if(name=="Bamba"){
            finalPrice = price + ChangePriceAmount;
        }else{

            finalPrice = price - ChangePriceAmount;
        }
        return finalPrice;
    }

    public String toString (){

        return  "Name of the Snack: "+name+ "\n"+
                "Name of the Company: "+comp+ "\n"+
                "Price before discount: "+this.price+ "\n"+
                "Price after discount: "+        finalPrice      + "\n";
    }
```

and another hint: name variables always with a lowercase letter at the beginning, it helps you to differentiate between class names and variable names.